# Trouble saving arraylist into a file

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedwriter

I have the following code that I call from main.
The trouble with the code, it saves the products 
as follows:
1,ipad,499.0,ELECTRONICS

1,ipad,499.0,ELECTRONICS
2,Java Ebook,19.99,BOOK

I don't understand where the first one comes from. 
Can you please provide us some pointers.

Thanks a lot...

```
public void saveProductsToDisk() {

    String filename = "/Users/paddy/UCSC/Workspace/productDB/src/productdb/savedProducts.csv";
    BufferedWriter output = null;
    try 
    {
        output =  new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        for (Product p: getAllProducts())
        {
            line.append(p.getId() <=0 ? "" : p.getId());
            line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            line.append(p.getName().trim().length() == 0? "" : p.getName());
            line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            line.append(p.getPrice() < 0 ? "" : p.getPrice());
            line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            line.append(p.getDept().toString());
            line.append("\n");
            output.write(line.toString());
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("IO error for " + filename +
                ": " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: A useful exercise is to walk through your code mentally when you run into such errors to picture what it's doing every step of the way. Do this and the error becomes obvious.

Comment: I will remember.. You guys make everyone a better programmer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
public void saveProductsToDisk() {

    String filename = 

"/Users/paddy/UCSC/Workspace/productDB/src/productdb/savedProducts.csv";
    BufferedWriter output = null;
    try 
    {
        output =  new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        StringBuilder line = null;
        for (Product p: getAllProducts())
        {
            line = new StringBuilder();
            line.append(p.getId() <=0 ? "" : p.getId());
            line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            line.append(p.getName().trim().length() == 0? "" : p.getName());
            line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            line.append(p.getPrice() < 0 ? "" : p.getPrice());
            line.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            line.append(p.getDept().toString());
            line.append("\n");
            output.write(line.toString());
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("IO error for " + filename +
                ": " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I jsut corrected the problem of user. But I accept your comment and updated it :-)

Comment: @Paddy You can accept the answer so that others can be benefited :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are re-using the same `line` variable with each iteration of your `for` loop.

Try re-initializing `line` at the top of your `for` loop like this:

```
...
StringBuilder line;
for (Product p: getAllProducts()) {
  line = new StringBuilder();
  line.append(p.getId() <=0 ? "" : p.getId());
  ...
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I will change my answer to use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). I was trying to fix the error without potentially breaking the OP's other code if `line` was being used elsewhere.